# Reformat values into separate columns

Tags: pandas, replace, fill

I'm trying to separate values into different columns in a pandas df. Specifically, I have strings that represent labels and timestamps in the same column. I'm hoping to separate these into separate columns. I'm just not sure what the more efficient process would be.

For the df below I want to separate the time strings into a separate column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value' : ['Foo X','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','Bar X','11:00','11:00','Cat X','12:00','12:00','12:00'],                 
    'Number' : [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,2,3],                      
    })
```

Out:

```
    Value  Number
0   Foo X       0
1   10:00       1
2   10:00       2
3   10:00       3
4   10:00       4
5   Bar X       0
6   11:00       1
7   11:00       2
8   Cat X       0
9   12:00       1
10  12:00       2
11  12:00       3
```

The issue is the amount of timestamps vary for each label so I cant just split every nth row. e.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':df['Value'].iloc[:1:4].values, 'Time':df['Value'].iloc[:1:4].values})
```

Another attempt could be to make a separate column to passing all values from df.Value and then replacing all timestamps with np.nan and subsetting the output. But I'm not sure if this is very efficient?

```
    Value  Number   Time
0   Foo X       0  Foo X
1   10:00       1  10:00
2   10:00       2  10:00
3   10:00       3  10:00
4   10:00       4  10:00
5   Bar X       0  Bar X
6   11:00       1  11:00
7   11:00       2  11:00
8   Cat X       0  Cat X
9   12:00       1  12:00
10  12:00       2  12:00
11  12:00       3  12:00
```

Intended Output:

```
  Value  Number   Time
0  Foo X       1  10:00
1  Foo X       2  10:00
2  Foo X       3  10:00
3  Foo X       4  10:00
4  Bar X       1  11:00
5  Bar X       2  11:00
6  Cat X       1  12:00
7  Cat X       2  12:00
8  Cat X       3  12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is distinguish time values by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing non matched values:

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df['Value'], errors='coerce').notna()
```

Or [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test pattern 2 digits numbers with `:`:

```
mask = df['Value'].str.contains(r'\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

Or id possible test for not equal `0`:

```
mask = df['Number'].ne(0)
```

Then create new column and replace `Value` to `NaN`s by `mask` with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and forward filling missing values, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Time'] = df['Value']
df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(mask).ffill()
df = df[mask].copy()
print (df)
    Value  Number   Time
1   Foo X       1  10:00
2   Foo X       2  10:00
3   Foo X       3  10:00
4   Foo X       4  10:00
6   Bar X       1  11:00
7   Bar X       2  11:00
9   Cat X       1  12:00
10  Cat X       2  12:00
11  Cat X       3  12:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function should give you the desired output.

```py
def process_dataframe(df):
    s = df.loc[df.Number==0]['Value']
    labels = s.to_list()
    a = s.index.to_list()
    a.append(df.index.size)
    repnum = [x2 - x1 - 1 for x1,x2 in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
    df2 = df.loc[df['Number']!=0].copy()
    df2['Time'] = df2['Value']
    df2['Value'] = s.repeat(repnum).to_list()
    return df2
process_dataframe(df)
```

> Output

```
  Value  Number   Time
0  Foo X       1  10:00
1  Foo X       2  10:00
2  Foo X       3  10:00
3  Foo X       4  10:00
4  Bar X       1  11:00
5  Bar X       2  11:00
6  Cat X       1  12:00
7  Cat X       2  12:00
8  Cat X       3  12:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [pd.Series.repat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) 
to create the `Value` column 
then select `Time` and `Number` through the use of [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
value_bool=pd.Series(['X' in key for key in df['Value']])
Value=df.loc[value_bool]['Value'] #selecting values ​​for the Value column
groups=df.groupby(value_bool.cumsum())
new_df=Value.repeat(groups.size()-1).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True) #create dataframe with new Value Column
new_df[['Number','Time']]=df.loc[~value_bool].reset_index(drop=True).reindex(columns=['Number','Value']) #creating Number and Time
```

**Output:**

```
   Value  Number   Time
0  Foo X       1  10:00
1  Foo X       2  10:00
2  Foo X       3  10:00
3  Foo X       4  10:00
4  Bar X       1  11:00
5  Bar X       2  11:00
6  Cat X       1  12:00
7  Cat X       2  12:00
8  Cat X       3  12:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using mask and ffill:

```
(
    df.assign(ind=df.Value.mask(df.Value.str.contains('^\d+:\d+')).ffill())
    .loc[lambda x: x.Number.ne(0)]
    .set_axis(['Time','Number', 'Value'], axis=1, inplace=False)
)
```